# Adding zoom lens function inside an anchor tag image

Tags: image, zooming, magnification

I want to add zoom/magnification lens function in my image which is inside an anchor tag as `<a href="imageurl"><img scr="#" /></a>`. When one clicks on the actual image, the url image shows up, and I would like the zoom lens to work on that one. Any help would be appreciated.